# Rotating turtle shape in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

New to Netlogo and having trouble figuring out how to rotate the image that is created by turtles. Would I have to move each individual turtle across the grid to make it seem like it is rotating or is there an easier way? The turtles should move and make the created shape rotate left like a Tetris piece.

```
to LShape
  ca
  crt 1 [
    set color grey
    set heading 1
    set shape "dot"
    set size 2
    setxy 0 0
 ]

  crt 1 [
    set color grey
    set heading 1
    set shape "dot"
    set size 2
    setxy 0.8 0
  ]

  crt 1 [
    set color grey
    set heading 1
    set shape "dot"
    set size 2
    setxy 1.6 0
  ]

  crt 1 [
    set color grey
    set heading 1
    set shape "dot"
    set size 2
    setxy 1.6 -0.8
  ]
end



to RotateL
  ask turtles [
   set heading heading + 10
  ]
end
```

Comment: Quick suggestion, it is better to just paste your code in the question than an image of your code. That allows us to quickly copypaste everything over to work with it ourselves.

Comment: You can find what you are looking for in the programming guide under "Tie" (
https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/). I don't have netlogo installed on this computer but can provide you some sample code once I get it up and running if you need it.

Comment: @LeirsW If possible could you provide some samples, I'm having a hard time with this and really wanna learn it. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I generated a small example for you. I first create a simple set of turtles and give them a location. Then I ask turtle 0 (Whom I chose as my focal turtle), to create a link to all other turtles. Finally I set all links to be tied. This means that if turtle 0 moves or turns, all other linked turtles will move and turn with him. Since I used `create-links-to`, all turtles moves together with turtle 0. If, however, you ask another turtle to move, only that turtle will move around. This allows you to easily reshape your figure

```
to setup
  ca
  resize-world 0 9 0 9
  
  crt 1[setxy 4 4]
  crt 1[setxy 4 5]
  crt 1[setxy 4 6]
  crt 1[setxy 5 4]  
  
  ask turtle 0 [create-links-to other turtles [tie] ]
  
end

to turn
  
  ask turtle 0 [set heading heading + 10]
  
end
```

You could use `create-links-with` instead to make the connection work in both directions. This could be useful if you sometimes want to make a different agent be the focal one. Below a small sample code of two turtles that walk forward by alternately letting either one turn.

```
to setup-2
  
  ca
  resize-world 0 9 0 9
  crt 1[setxy 0 3]
  crt 1[
    setxy 0 6
    create-link-with turtle 0 [tie]
  ]

end

to step-left
  
  ask turtle 0 [set heading heading + 20]
  
  
end

to step-right
  
  ask turtle 1 [set heading heading - 20]
  
end
```

If you don't want them to be tied together anymore, you can simply ask the links to `untie`. The links will still be there for retying if you would want them to.
Finally, you can make the links invisible if they are cluttering up the image with `ask links [hide-link]`